# linux expect + ssh command output is missing after some piping

Tags: shell, expect

I want execute some command(eg,pwd) by ssh.

```
ssh root@jump pwd
```

I use expect to wrap it,So it become "e" command, it works well.

```
./e jump
```

But output was missing after pipe,can not display result of "pwd" command

```
cat list.txt | xargs -I xx ./e xx
```

**here is the e script**

```
[root@jump tmp]# cat ./e
 expect -d -c '
        spawn   ssh root@'$1' pwd
         expect "*assword:" {
          send "r41\r"
          sleep 1
        }

        sleep 3
 '
```

**while ssh after pipe is okay, echo xx just for adding more pipe **

```
echo xx | ssh root@jump pwd
```

Comment: Are you expecting the `echo xx` value to be given as an input to the `expect` program ? Sorry, I couldn't understand that. you are logging into the remote via ssh. What is the need of `echo xx` here ?

Comment: echo xx just for piping. re-edit for showing purpose

Comment: user3073309, Whether my answer worked ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `;` to seperate command in compound statement

```
echo xx | ssh root@jump; pwd
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the `echo xx` redirection here. But, in the expect code, just add one `expect` statement to wait for the `pwd` to get executed

```
expect -c '
        spawn ssh dinesh@myremotemachine pwd
        expect "*word:" {
                send "root\r"

                #The reason for adding '/' here is to wait for the 
                #directory to get printed and since the directory
                #will have the char '/' such as 

                #/users/dinesh/pgms/expect 

                expect "/"

                sleep 1
        }
        sleep 3
        puts "leaving"
'
```

I have tested this in my remote machine and you can customize the expect character based on your expected character.  If this also not helping, provide your error output.